# Skrollr: Multiple instances

Tags: skrollr

I have two columns that I would like to animate separately with a trigger. As I understand it: Skrollr only allows one instantiation on a page. Does anyone know if it's possible to have multiple instances that can be turned off and on?

I've started a [working example here](http://play.meyouand.us/130401-skrollr-multi/split2.html):

- The grey column will activate the Skrollr instance when clicking on its "Activate!" button. (The "Destroy!" button will remove its instance.)
- I would like to isolate the Skrollr animation to just the grey column, but as you can see in this example, the yellow/orange column is also being activated.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways

1. Remove/add the data attributes between the destroy/init calls and only add them to the elements you want
2. Use two constants, defined as a function and toggle them between `0` and `1e6` (or something really large). Now the elements with the large one will effectively not be rendered (given you're using `edgeStrategy` `reset`)
3. Monkey patch the `refresh` method (without touching the skrollr code itself). Skrollr uses it internally when using `init`. Now you can patch it to use `leftColumn.getElementsByTagName('*')` or all elements in the right column when no parameter is passed. This way initializing will only affect elements inside one of the columns.

Comment: Thanks for this strategy—I'm going to give it a try!

Comment: I hope you didn't get it wrong. Those are three different strategies. Choose **one** of them.